# terraform retrieve azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy backup_policy_id

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm building a terraform template to enable Azure recovery service vault for a VM. The recovery service vault is existing as well as the backup policy. I need a Data Source to retrieve the backup policy id, which is required by the resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm"

I can find data source of "azurerm_recovery_services_vault", but cannot find a data source for for recovery service policy. Then, to achieve this objective, I have to put a resource like

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm" "test"{
  name                = "DefaultPolicy"
  resource_group_name = "${var.recovery_vault_resource_group_name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${var.recovery_vault_name}"

  backup = {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "09:30"
  }
  retention_daily = {
    count = 10
  }
}
```

The challenge is that the DefaultPolicy can vary from vault to vault. And I don't want to change it or make it the same across my whole tenant. 
Is there any way I can retrieve the recovery policy ID without creating one?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/recovery_services_vault.html) provider reference data resource only returns recovery services vault: id, location, sku and tags.

So there currently is no way of doing that in terraform.

Comment: Well, that's very sucks. Hardly believable. If so, it's really a bad design. Anyone concur this answer?

Comment: If you want some extra functionality then add a feature request for it on the provider project or implement it yourself. Ultimately the providers can't do everything because, outside of very popular/core functionality that may be implemented by Hashicorp/MS employees, they rely on people who use Terraform to contribute that functionality.

Comment: can I confirm whether Terraform provides this feature before contribute blindly?